# ALAssestsLibrary activates only if device option is selected in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to use ALAssetsLibrary  framework for displaying photos from the photo album.But while editing the code i found that
1)codesense shows the methods under this framework only if the option 'device' is selected in the left dropdown menu in xcode.

2)Moreover  when i tried to build and run on the simulator, the array that was supposed to hold objects representing the images was empty although there were two images in the simulator.

3)Im using blocks in the code, into which am not able to step while debugging.

Do these two things mean that the framework is functional only when running in the device?I dont have a device with me right now , so cant check for myself.

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != NULL) {
                NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
                [photosArray addObject:result];

    }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }

};


ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError    *error) {
                                NSLog(@"Failure");
                             }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me using the iPhone simulator with iOS 4.2 and Xcode 3.

Are you enumerating all the groups in enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:?

There is a [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/) which uses ALAssetsGroupAlbum.
If you are using this tutorial, use ALAssetsGroupAll instead of ALAssetsGroupAlbum to get the photos you saved on the simulator.

Comment: @FrenchKiss Dev:sadly its not working for me,i have two pictures in the simulator, but the array that should be holding them remains empty.And i cant put a breakpoint inside the block code also

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary and blocks need iOS 4 or more. Please copy your code here. If breakpoints do not work, try using NSLog to see if your blocks are called.

Comment: I am using the same sample code as you and everything is working fine on the simulator. Maybe something is wrong with your project settings. Try to create a new view-based project and copy/paste the sample code into the viewDidLoad method.